# Referencing images in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, xcode, cordova, sencha-touch

I recently wrapped an HTML5 (Sencha Touch) app that I have been developing using PhoneGap in Xcode. I have places in my app where I reference images, like the following:

```
logo = {
        xtype: 'component',
        html: '<img src="http://localhost/resources/logo.png" />',
        height: 100,
        width: 200
};
```

I would like to know how I need to alter this code in order to reference an image that I have copied into Xcode, seeing as how this code no longer works for my PhoneGap app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `logo.png` is in a folder called `resources` under your projects `www` folder, you could try a relative URL:

```
logo = {
        xtype: 'component',
        html: '<img src="resources/logo.png" />',
        height: 100,
        width: 200
};
```

I am not that up on Sencha Touch, but the `<img src="resources/logo.png" />` would be correct for an image in that location from within a vanilla PhoneGap application.